# Shrub Identification

Tags: identification, shrubs

Location: Columbus, Ohio

Early in the season, maybe too early to identify.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a viburnum of some type, possibly a Viburnum carlesii or V.x burkwoodii cultivar if the flowers are fragrant. There are a large number of cultivars in the Viburnum genus, from many species, which can make identification somewhat tricky from a photo.

Comment: Oh the smell is extremely strong once it blooms.  In fact, my wife and I wonder if someone is smoking marijuana or if a skunk died sometimes.

Comment: Hmm. This sounds like a plant that has flowers that are fly-pollinated rather than bee-pollinated. The two suggestions in my answer are bee-pollinated.

Comment: OK, I've checked some references. The two possibilities are mentioned are considered to be fragrant and smell like cloves. Personally, I find both types very pleasing - something to go out of your way to sniff.

Comment: I would use word Pungent to describe the smell.